# Question about integrating SQL into C# apps was questionably put on hold

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598936/integrating-a-sql-query-into-asp-c-sharp), which I didn't ask but would like to answer, is on hold. My edit to try and make it more concise was accepted, but the question stays on hold.

There are about half a dozen ways of integrating SQL into C# apps. ADO, Micro ORMs, SQL in string literals (most common) vs embedded resource (much better). The problem is old, but there are [new solutions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst) (disclaimer: which I wrote). I think this is potentially a *very good* question.

Comment: somewhat related: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Answer (score 19):

It might be a good or interesting question, but it is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.
Even after your edits, the actual question remains:

> I have noticed that some people use a QueryBuilder but are there other ways of doing this?

And you concede that:

> There are about half a dozen ways of integrating SQL into C# apps.

This is textbook "too broad". There are a large number of different options, no guidance provided in the question that could be used to discern which of those options is most appropriate, and opinions about which is the "best" will be varied. These are not the types of questions that Stack Overflow is designed to handle.

Also, pardon my cynicism, but it seems like you just want to re-open the question so that you can promote a tool/approach you developed. And even if you have completely noble intentions, the question has already attracted [one low-quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41599270/366904) along these lines, which is another reason why we do not allow such broad questions—they attract answers like this.

Comment: Very good then. No need to excuse yourself. I imagine that my open-source tool developing is no more noble, or well paid, than your stack overflow moderating.

Comment: I don't know if that was supposed to be a little back-handed jab or not, but I do a whole lot more than "moderating" here, and I wasn't even one of the people who voted to close your question. I was just explaining the reasoning.